# Scheme-modifying vector of vectors

Tags: list, vector, functional-programming, scheme

I am a beginner programist. I have to write a simple program in pure Scheme that will print out a rectangle of given height and width (for example 4,6):

```
111111
100001
100001
111111
```

1 is a black border, 0 is an empty space.

I am encountering an obstacle.
My solution is a vector of vectors `#(#(111111) (100001) (100001) (100001))` because it is easy to modify later. First I create vector of vectors filled with zeros and later I want to set its values to 1.

The problem is that for example if I want to change the first element of first vector to 1 I dont know why the program sets first elements of ALL vectors to 1. So I want to get:
: `#(100000) (000000) (000000) (000000))` but i get `#(#(100000) (100000) (100000) (100000))`

The code is:

```
(vector-set! (vector-ref vect 0) 0 "1")
```

Does anyone have an explenation on maybe an easier solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will avoid the [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) problem:

```
(define (make-board n)
  (let ((table (make-vector n)))
    (let filling ((i 0))
      (if (= i n)
          table
          (begin (vector-set! table i (make-vector n 0))
                 (filling (+ i 1)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, you've constructed the 2-d vector like so:

```
(define row #(0 0 0 0 0 0))
(define table (vector row row row row))
```

Then what you have is a vector, called `table`, that holds four *references* to `row`, while what you need is four *copies* of `row` that can be independently modified. You can get that with

```
(define table (vector (vector-copy row)
                      (vector-copy row)
                      (vector-copy row)
                      (vector-copy row)))
```

(In technical terms, your vectors are *sharing structure*. Often, this is a good thing, but when you're using destructive modification, e.g. `vector-set!`, it may lead to surprising results.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have post this earlier:
I create it with:

'(define vect (make-vector h (make-vector w 0)))'

Is it the problem ?

Comment: @MaciekBąk: yes, the exact same situation ensues. You create one vector of size `w`, then you pass a reference to that to the outer `make-vector` which just repeats the reference instead of copying the vector.

Comment: OK I understand.
However I can not use vector-copy or any other additional libraries. Is there a simple way to construct a 2D vector of h-height and w-width so that all rows are separate ?

Comment: @MaciekBąk: just construct four vectors, separately. But `vector-copy` is not an "additional library". It's part of the core language just as much as `vector-set!` is.